# Linq counting second grouping and counting without grouping

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I'm trying to build a summary query that i will be using for statistics.

i have a dataTable with the folowing columns (approx 18000 rows) :

```
Artist / Album / file_path (one for each song) / rating /
```

each artist has 1 or several album with has songs and each songs have a rating

I want to have the following result :

For each artist ID (more reliable than the artist name), the total number of albums, the total number of songs, and the total number of ratings equal to 5.

```
Artist x / #album / #songs / #rating = 5 / song.first() //in song.first i have access to the file path, it can be any file path from the artist hence the first one.
```

I've been pulling my hair for several hours now and i cannot manage to get the # of albums per artist :( This is what i've been trying so far :

i have a Class for the query :

```
  public class art_detail
    {
        public string artiste { get; set; }
        public string fp { get; set; } // the file_path
        public int nbr_album { get; set; }
        public int nbr_song { get; set; }
        public int nbr_rat5 { get; set; }
    }
```

this is the query i came up to :

```
            var result = from res in Globals.ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable() // the table
           .GroupBy(x =>  new { art = x.Field<int>("Artist_ID"), alb = x.Field<string>("album") })
           .Select(x => new art_detail { artiste = x.Select(p =>p.Field<string>("artiste")).First(), fp = x.Select(p=>p.Field<string>("file_path")).First(), nbr_album = x.Key.alb.Count() })
           .OrderBy(x => x.artiste)
                  select res;
```

The count is unfortunately completely wrong and i have no idea how to get the # of rating = 5 :(

Thanks for the help !

Edit : 
Here is my query to make it work :

```
               var table = Globals.ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable();
               var stats = table.GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("Artist_ID"))
                .Select(x => new art_detail
                {
                     artiste = x.Select(p=>p.Field<string>("artiste")).First(),
                     nbr_album = x.Select(y => y.Field<string>("album")).Distinct().Count(),
                     fp = x.Select(y => y.Field<string>("file_path")).FirstOrDefault(),
                     nbr_song = x.Count(),
                     nbr_rat5 = x.Count(y => y.Field<int>("Rating") == 5)
                 });
```

Simpler than what i thought :)

Comment: Since you are grouping by artist AND album, there will be multiple elements for one artist and multiple albums. So you should propbably group by artist only and then get the count of albums etc.

Comment: If you want to report stats for each artist, you'll need to use GroupBy. Because that's what you're doing. You're grouping data. If you're just looking for one artist, then you can avoid grouping by using a where statement and SelectMany() https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a table whose schema matches this class:

```
public class Song
{
    public string ArtistID { get; set; }
    public string Album { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
}
```

and given a LINQ source, you have the following query:

```
IQueryable<Song> table = /*insert source*/;
var stats = table.GroupBy(x => x.ArtistID);
                 .Select(x => new art_detail
                 {
                     artiste = x.Key,
                     nbr_album = x.Select(y => y.Album).Distinct().Count(),
                     nbr_song = x.Count(),
                     nbr_rat5 = x.Count(y => y.Rating == 5),
                 });
```

Comment: Thank you naasking, i made it work with your input. gonna edith my question for future reference :)

Answer (score 1):

I used head compiled query as it seemed more understandable for me in this case:

**Example model:**

```
public class Artist
{
    public string ArtistID { get; set; }
    public string Album { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfSongs { get; set; }
}
```

**Creating some dummy records for Usher and Beyonce:**

```
//Usher
var artistOne = new Artist() 
{
    ArtistID = "Usher",
    Album = "Lit",
    FilePath = "dummy/path/here",
    Rating = 5,
    NumberOfSongs = 9
};
var artistTwo = new Artist() 
{
    ArtistID = "Usher",
    Album = "Sick",
    FilePath = "dummy/path/here",
    Rating = 5,
    NumberOfSongs = 11
};
var artistThree = new Artist() 
{
    ArtistID = "Usher",
    Album = "Dope",
    FilePath = "dummy/path/here",
    Rating = 4,
    NumberOfSongs = 14
};

//Beyonce
var artistFour = new Artist() 
{
    ArtistID = "Beyonce",
    Album = "Hot",
    FilePath = "dummy/path/here",
    Rating = 5,
    NumberOfSongs = 8
};
var artistFive = new Artist() 
{
    ArtistID = "Beyonce",
    Album = "Fire",
    FilePath = "dummy/path/here",
    Rating = 4,
    NumberOfSongs = 16
};

var listOfArtist = new List<Artist> { artistOne, artistTwo, artistThree, artistFour, artistFive };
```

**Running query:**

```
var result =  from a in listOfArtist
              where a.Rating == 5
              group a by a.ArtistID into art
              select new
              {
                 artist = art.Key,
                 numberOfAlbums = art.Count(),
                 numberOfSongs = art.Sum(d => d.NumberOfSongs),
              };
```

**Results:**

[image]

Hope this helps =)

Comment: thanks Coke, i didnt manage to make it work. I have two issues: 1/ I dont have a NumberOfSongs field but i actually have one row per song. 2/ i cant manage to retrieve the file_path. but i managed to make it work with naasking answer below. I'll edit my question with the answer.