# linq where statement subject to a checkbox value

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I want to run a `linq` query and i have a `checkbox` to tell me if i need to include some elements or not.
So that means the `.where` statement have to check for the `checkbox` status.

That linq is gathering some statistics about a mp3 database and i built it with the help of Naasking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62398248/linq-counting-second-grouping-and-counting-without-grouping)

I managed to include a ? : statement within the .where clause ie :

```
  var stats = from res in Globals.ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
   .Where(x => checkBox1.Checked == false ? x.Field<string>("some_field") == "some_criteria" : 
   x.Field<string>("some_field") == "everything")
```

But my issue is that when the checkbox is checked, that means that i dont need the `.where` statement as i'm using everything, in that example the "everything" is not a criteria, it's supposed to be no criteria at all.

Is there a way to have the equivalent of a * in a `.where` ? otherwise how can i manage this situation ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within a `Where` predicate, you could use `x => true` to match everything. We can combine that notion with the alternative side of the ternary, updating your example to the following (note I've broken the query into two lines for purposes of this answer only):

```
var stats = Globals.ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable();
 // pass "where true" as alternative 
var result = stats.Where(x => checkBox1.Checked == false ? x.Field<string>("some_field") == "whatever" : true);
```

After applying some simplification to our boolean logic, this then becomes:

```
var result = stats.Where(x => checkBox1.Checked || x.Field<string>("some_field") == "whatever");
```

Of course we'd only really ever do either of these if we had a *need* to combine the logical checks into a single clause. Because after all, `where true` is the same as not applying any filtering at all:

```
var stats = Globals.ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable();

if (!checkBox1.Checked)
{
   stats = stats.Where(x => x.Field<string>("some_field") == "whatever");
}
var result = stats.ToList();
```

**Note**: the example in your question and the plain English explanation you provide are at odds with each other. It's not entirely clear if being checked means everything or filtered. This answer follows that of the example--checked means everything. If it's the opposite (unchecked means everything) the examples would become:

```
// example 1
var result = stats.Where(x => checkBox1.Checked ? x.Field<string>("some_field") == "whatever" : true);
// example 2
var result = stats.Where(x => !checkBox1.Checked || x.Field<string>("some_field") == "whatever");
// example 3 (if statement only) 
if (checkBox1.Checked)
{
   stats = stats.Where(x => x.Field<string>("some_field") == "whatever");
}
```

Comment: thanks @pinkfloydx33, it works great :) the simplification to the boolean logic is plain awesome. You were right, my wording was incorrect, i modified it, your first answer was the right one. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can skip `.Where` when checkbox not checked

```
var query = Globals.ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable();

if (checkBox1.Checked)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.Field<string>("some_field")); 
}

var result = query.ToArray();
```

Comment: thanks Fabio, but my issue is that the query is gathering statistics so the "initial" perimeter is critical. in other terms, the condition will affect the results

Comment: @SebastienChemouny, sorry, equivalent of `*`(everything) in `.Where` clause would be not use `.Where`. Can you elaborate what you mean by `*` in `.Where`? Do you have some list of accepted values? What you mean gathering statistics?

Comment: Fabio, i'm basically counting records using criteria (you can look at the link in the question) so if i'm using your solution, the record counting will have happened before the setting up of the perimeter which doesnt work. I do not have a short list of accepted values unfort., it can be tens of different values.

Comment: @SebastienChemouny, so what value you want to search for when checkbox is checked Album, Song or Artist? Feel free to update question with more context from your original one.